# Integration on smooth manifolds

Tags: real-analysis, integration, differential-geometry, lebesgue-integral, smooth-manifolds

Ive got a question regarding integration on smooth manifolds.

Currently I attempting a course on differential geometry (we call it here informationsource (1)) and simultaniously Real Analysis 3 (information source (2)) and I worked through most of Jänichs Vector Analysis (information source (3)).

In both classes I am reaching Stokes theorem which states under certain conditions:

$\int_Md\omega=\int_{\partial M}\omega$

In Real Analysis 3 we restrict our observations to manifolds in $\mathbb{R}^n$ which moves around most of the work we need to do in differential geometry regarding continuos charts.

In all 3 Sources ive learned about Differentialforms and that if we try to integrate over a n-Manifold we will need a volumeform which is a nowhere vanishing n-form.

Now Source (2) started the integration chapter with introducing k-cubes, which are an generalized notion of a curve from $[0,1]^n\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$, notice that source (2) does not need charts since we restrict the observation to submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Then it was stated that:

$$\int_{\mathbb{I}^n}\omega=\int_{\mathbb{I}^n} f(x)dx_1\wedge...\wedge dx_n:=\int_{\mathbb{I}^n}fd\lambda_n$$

with n-form $\omega=f(x)dx_1\wedge...\wedge dx_n$ and $\lambda_n$ the lebesgue messure.

Here starts my questioning: why can we simply define it that way? I do know, that forms have the advantage to be integrated with an orientation and messure ignore the notion of orientation, probably one would say:

$$\int_{\mathbb{I}^n} f(x)dx_{\sigma(1)}\wedge...\wedge dx_{\sigma(n)}:=\text{sgn}(\sigma)\int_{\mathbb{I}^n}fd\lambda_n$$

to keep the orientation and to for example justify our usual convention that:

$$\int^b_af(x)dx=-\int^a_bf(x)dx$$

But isnt $\omega=f(x)dx_1\wedge...\wedge dx_n=f(x)\det(X_1,...,X_n)$, why is it reasonable to basically define $\det:=d\lambda_n$.

I do understand, that $\det$ meassures the oriented volume of the parallelopiped  spanned by the input vectors, and that the Lebesgueintegral basically "sums all the little cubes" in a certain set in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

The more general Integral got defined over any "general" n-cube via:

$c:[0,1]^n\longrightarrow U$ as any continuous function:

$$\int_c \omega = \int_{\mathbb{I}^n}c^*\omega$$

which is equal, if I am not wrong to: $\int_{\mathbb{I}^n}f(c(x))\det(Dc(x)X_1,...,Dc(x)X_n)$

Source (1) stopped by the way directly on:

$$\int_M \omega=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}(\Psi_U^{-1})^*\omega = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)dx_1\wedge...\wedge dx_n $$

If here is $\omega$ with compact support and $(U,\Psi_U)$ being a chart containing the whole support. (The technical part with partition of unity is no problem so I stay with the simpel case) And $f(x)dx_1\wedge...\wedge dx_n =\omega |_U= (\Psi_U^{-1})^*\omega$.

Here my Professor stopped the integration process and didnt go further into detail. I assume from source (1) that also here one will now just use the Lebesgueintegral so solve: $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}fd\lambda_n$... so I came to the conclusion that the whole problem for me in general is: Why can we say: $\det=dx_1\wedge...\wedge dx_n= d\lambda_n$? Any more details into integration over smooth manifolds is happy apprecitated, because my goal is, to completly grasp the "intuition" behind the mechanism.

Thank you :)

Comment: Actually it is very possible to define the integral over an $n$-form exactly as you say (in $\mathbb R^n$). For example, this is done in one of my favorite books (in german): [Konrad Königsberger, *Analysis II*, Vierte Auflage. Springer, 2001; Kapitel 13.5, Seite 418].

Comment: I dont have the book in my shelf currently :) would you mind explaining, why it is reasonable to jump directly to lebesgue messure ?

Comment: If you take the determinant of $n$ vectors in $\mathbb R^n$, you get (up to sign) exactly the volume of the [Parallelepiped](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Parallelepiped.html) spanned by these vectors. So this is why loosely speaking, the determinant measures volume (and so it makes sense to define the integral over it as the Lebesgue integral).

Comment: But the determinant does require also a vectorfield, to give me some sort of density in a certain point, so it takes more arguments then lebesgue messure, doesnt it?

Comment: Sorry if this is a bit abstract (I am not good at explaining this topic in concrete terms): There is an important distinction between a *differential form* and a *multilinear form*: I will work on $\mathbb R^n$ only for simplicity. A differential $k$-form $\omega$ on $\mathbb R^n$ is a function which maps each point $p\in\mathbb R^n$ to $\omega_p\in \Lambda^k((\mathbb R^n)^*)$. Here I am using $\Lambda^k((\mathbb R^n)^*)$ to denote the space of all multilinear $k$-forms on $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: So, in short, a differential form *maps each point to a multilinear form*. One can now prove that there is, up to constant multiple, *only one* multilinear $n$-form on $\mathbb R^n$, namely the determinant. In other words, $$\Lambda^n((\mathbb R^n)^*)=\{c \det: c\in\mathbb R\}.$$ So, a differential $n$-form $\omega$ on $\mathbb R^n$, will *at each point*, be equal to a constant multiple of the determinant. So $\omega$ can always be written as $$\omega_p=f(p)\det$$ for some $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$.

Comment: Now, with $f(p)=1$ for all $p\in\mathbb R^n$, you get the differential form which is constant and always equal to the determinant. In this case, when you integrate, you get exactly the integral with respect to the Lebesgue measure. But of course, you are free to choose your own $f$. So you can choose any $f$ which is absolutely integrable and you get the integral with respect to the measure (informally written) $f\,d\lambda^n$. Like you say, this $f$ can be interpreted as giving a "density" or "weight" to each point in $\mathbb R^n$, and it is closely related to probability density functions.

Comment: (For example, if $f:\mathbb R^n\to[0,\infty[$ is measurable and integrable in the Lebesgue sense with $\int_{\mathbb R^n} f=1$, then it is a probability density function over $\mathbb R^n$.)

Comment: I think it clicked, with thinking about the Transformationformular for the Lebesgueintegral we get for any $C^1$ function $\phi: R^n\longrightarrow R^n$ $\int_{\phi(R^n)}f(y)dy=\int_{R^n}f(\phi(x))|\det D\phi(x)|dx$ taking now: $f=1$ we get: $Vol(\phi(R^n))=\int_{\phi(R^n)}d\lambda_n=\int_{\phi(R^n)}dy=\int_{R^n}|\det D\phi(x)|dx=\int_{R^n}\phi^*dx_1\wedge...\wedge dx_n$

Comment: Yes exactly! (Except $\phi$ needs to be a $C^1$-diffeomorphism .)

Comment: Doesnt Lemma of Sard gives us, that the critical Points are always a messure zero set

Comment: The set of *critical values* of $f$ is indeed a set of Lebesgue measure $0$, as you say. But that is not the issue. To illustrate the issue: Take $f\in C^1(\mathbb R;\mathbb R), f(x)=\cos(x)$. (Note that $f$ is not a diffeomorphism.) Then $$\text{Vol}(f(\mathbb R))=2,$$ but $\int_{\mathbb R}\lvert f'\rvert=\infty$.

Comment: (Also there are possibly some small technical issues with the sign of $\det$, but that is not the point of this discussion.)

Comment: Ah of course thank you! I also checked my script again, Sards Lemma just soften from Diffeo to $C^1$ bijective.